# Get the current Window without native code in GWT?

Tags: gwt

I need to get my current window in GWT (the one is referenced by $wnd in JavaScript, I pass it to the [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html)).

I can easily do this by writing a short native method that returns $wnd (type of JavaScriptObject) and everyting works for me. But I wonder, is it really so that I need a JavaScript wrapper for the single line action so obvious?

Is it a way to get the value of $wnd as JavaScriptObject without using the native JavaScript code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [Window](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/Window.html) object in GWT.

It does exactly what you are proposing by accessing the javascript #wnd object.

Comment: This is a class. Where is the instance?

Comment: Can you not use the static TOP_WINDOW variable from the [ScriptInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/core/client/ScriptInjector.html)?

Comment: Yes, it works for me if I explicitly set call .setWindow(ScriptInjector.TOP_WINDOW). It did not work for me without this assignment.